# Only list host in the bash prompt if running remotely?

Tags: bash, ps1

I'm trying to modify my Bash prompt to my will; this is how `$PS1` looks at the moment (with colors edited out for clarity):

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Which results in:

```
andreas@tablet-2710p-ubuntu:~$
```

Can I tweak the prompt so it hides the `@tablet-2710p-ubuntu` bit (represented by `@\h`) if I'm running the current Bash session *locally*, rather than accessing a remote server?

I'd also rather not hard-code it (for instance, just replacing any occurrence of `tablet-2710p-ubuntu`) for portability's sake, and in case the host name is changed later.

Comment: See this question about how you can detect if a session is local or over ssh: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As brought out in [*How can I detect if the shell is controlled from SSH?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9607/5769), if either of the variables `$SSH_CLIENT` or `$SSH_TTY` are set, it means you are connecting through SSH.

If you are on a Debian-based system (such as Ubuntu) you can edit your `.bashrc` to something like this in order to achieve the desired effect (note that the string that `PS1` is set to [has to be defined with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23820369/617937), not single quotes as it is by default):

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
    if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
        host="@\[\033[1;34m\]\h\[\033[00m\]"
    else
        host="@\h"
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]${host}:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
else
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u${host}:\w\$ "
fi
unset host
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Which results in the following:

[image: BASH: Hide host when running locally, show host when connecting over SSH]

**Side note:** These changes should be made on the `.bashrc` (or `.profile`, depending on the distribution) on server you are connecting **to** over SSH. Setting them in your own local Bash profile has no effect on what is displayed when you connect to other remote servers.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want something like below? :

```
if [ "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then 
    PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
else
    PS1='\u:\w\$ '
fi
```

Comment: +1 This worked just fine, but I added a second answer with a bit more detail.

Comment: And in `zsh`: `if [ "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then <NL>
    export PS1="%n@%m:%1~%(!.#.$) " <NL>
else <NL>
    export PS1="%n:%1~%(!.#.$) " <NL>
fi` where `<NL>` are new lines.

Comment: ^^ Note: You shouldn't usually need to export PS1, since only the local shell uses it and the *shrc is generally sourced by any child shell instances as well. Plus, SSH_CONNECTION is an environment variable, thus it is always exported unless you explicitly un-export it.