# Unable to add escape sequences dynamically for 'PS1'

Tags: bash

Say I want to include an escape sequence dynamically:

```
if [ -n $something ]; then
    user="\u"
else
    user="admin"
fi
PS1='$user@\h$ '
```

The problem is, instead of filling in the user name, my prompt looks like this:

```
\u@ubuntu-1$
```

Even if I escape the backslash (`user="\\u"`) it still does not print out the user name. How do I get the prompt to look like this:

```
andreas@ubuntu-1$
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your prompt to look like?

Comment: What version of bash do you use? I've just checked your example and it does work as expected (BASH_VERSION=`bash-3.2.51(1)-release`).

Comment: @merlin2011 I want my prompt to look like the final example I gave: `andreas@ubuntu-1$ `

Comment: @user3159253 Found the problem, the example I gave uses double quotes, [the assignment in my `.bashrc` file](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/ed12b30977acc529163c) uses single quotes. The example has been updated with this new information.

Comment: Why not use double quotes? You need them for variable interpolation to work.

Comment: @merlin2011 Add that as an answer. The single quotes were already there in `.bashrc` by default; are they actually required to be single quotes (looking at the rest of my "default `PS1` contents"), or can I switch over to double quotes without issues?

Comment: You can use either type of quotes, depending on your need. Single quotes are often used to delay expansion until `PS1` is actually displayed, for example, `PS1='$(date) '` to display the current date, rather than the date when `PS1` was defined.

Comment: @IQAndreas, If you are still having problems I have updated the answer with another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes when you are trying to interpolate variables and want them to expand.

You also have another option, instead of dealing with `\u` and complications with when the interpretation of it happens.

```
if [ -n $something ]; then
    user=`whoami`
else
    user="admin"
fi
PS1="$user@\h$ "
```